# Getting error on changing few syntax python 2.7.7

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm getting an error on changing `if 'x' == 'y'` to `if 'y' in 'x'`
More accuratly, I can encrypt/decrypt with the first one but not with the second with only that changes.

Example script (not whole code):
The working one

```
for char in sourceString:
    if (n == k or n == -k):
        n = 0
    if (cc == 'decryption'):
        const = -const
        cc = 'off'
    if char.isupper():
        resultString += encrypt(char, UPPER_LETTERS);
        if (c == 'encryption'):
            n += p
        elif (c == 'decryption'):
            n -= p
        else:
            break

    elif char.islower():
        resultString += encrypt(char, LOWER_LETTERS);
        if (c == 'encryption'):
            n += p
        elif (c == 'decryption'):
            n -= p
        else:
            break
    else:
        resultString += char;
        if (c == 'encryption'):
            n += p
        elif (c == 'decryption'):
            n -= p
        else:
            break
```

Here I get an error:

```
for char in sourceString:
    if (n == k or n == -k):
        n = 0
    if ('de' or 'De' or 'dE' or 'DE' in cc):
        const = -const
        cc = 'off'
    if char.isupper():
        resultString += encrypt(char, UPPER_LETTERS);
        if ('en' or 'En' or 'eN' or 'EN' in c):
            n += p
        elif ('de' or 'De' or 'dE' or 'DE' in c):
            n -= p
        else:
            break

    elif char.islower():
        resultString += encrypt(char, LOWER_LETTERS);
        if ('en' or 'En' or 'eN' or 'EN' in c):
            n += p
        elif ('de' or 'De' or 'dE' or 'DE' in c):
            n -= p
        else:
            break
    else:
        resultString += char;
        if ('en' or 'En' or 'eN' or 'EN' in c):
            n += p
        elif ('de' or 'De' or 'dE' or 'DE' in c):
            n -= p
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't chain `or`s like that; it should be `'de' in c or 'De' in c or #...`.

Alternatively, it looks like you can just lowercase all strings in `c` (using `str.lower()`) and just check `if 'de' in c`.

Yet another method is to do something like this:

```
if any(x in c for x in ['de', 'De', 'dE', 'DE']):
```

Finally, the `cc` in the line `if ('de' or 'De' or 'dE' or 'DE' in cc):` should probably just be a `c`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm amused every time i see that kind of mistakes :)

First of all you don't need the '()' in your if condition
if you write:

```
if 'en' or ...somthing:
```

python looking for a condition **between** your 'or's. That mean if you want to make more then one condition, you need to do somthing like that:

```
if 'en' in c or 'En' in c or 'eN' in c or 'EN' in c:
```

I know your version looks more like english, but it's doesn't make sense for the computer.